# Select count group by combined with any

Tags: sql, group-by

There is this query:

```
select town, count(town) 
from user
group by town
```

which returns

```
Town         Count
Copenhagen   5
NewYork      6
Athens       7
```

But I would like an additional line which shows all towns number:

```
Town         Count
Copenhagen   5
NewYork      6
Athens       7
All          18
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way, but I believe this should work:

```
WITH counts_by_town AS (
    SELECT town, COUNT(town) AS cnt
    FROM user
    GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT town, cnt
FROM counts_by_town
UNION ALL
SELECT 'All' AS town, SUM(cnt) AS cnt
FROM counts_by_town;
```

Comment: Thks, any chance to have a request without UNION which seems to be vert slow?